# Failed summing/adding every other component inside an integer array

Tags: c, arrays, validation, integer, cs50

I continue my quest to store an input credit card number and validate it.

1) User types hipothetic credit card number, like 1234567898769999 (stored as string).
2) Convert string to an array of integers int digits[].
3) Multiply digitis in positions 1, 3, 5 ... last odd position by 2,
for instance 2*2, 2*4, 2*6, 2*8, 2*8, 2*6, 2*9, 2*9.
4) Store them in the same array and position [4,8,12,16,16, 12, 18,18].
5) Sum digits in positions 0, 2, 4 ... last even position.

Trying to run the code below with abnormal values appearing:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    string cc_string;

    printf("Please enter a credit card number:\n");

    //Capture credit card number
    cc_string = GetString();

    // Array of integers for credit card digits int cc_digits[15];
    int sum_evens, sum_odds = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {   
        cc_digits[i] = cc_string[i] - '0';

        //Sum digits in even positions (0 ... 14)
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum_evens = sum_evens + cc_digits[i];

            //Checking values
            printf("cc_digits[%d] = %d; Sum_evens = %d\n", i, cc_digits[i], sum_evens);
        }

        else if (i % 2 == 1)
        {
            //Multiplies values in each position by 2 and stores in the same position
            cc_digits[i] = 2 * cc_digits[i];
            sum_odds = sum_odds + cc_digits[i];

            //Checking values
            printf("cc_digits[%d] = %d; Sum_odds = %d\n", i, cc_digits[i], sum_odds);
        }
    }
}
```

Will anybody have a clue about what is going on here?
It has been three days since I have tried to solve this.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: For the sake of copying your code, can you please remove the '>' characters on the left?

Comment: You should check that the input string *has* 16 digits, before trying to examine possibly non-existant digits. And in a real world implementation, the card number should be specifically cleared before entering another. My colleague made a prototype safe with PIN entry, and was crestfallen when I opened it just by pressing `Enter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> abnormal values appearing

```
int sum_evens, sum_odds = 0;
```

Here you have not initialized the value of `sum_evens`, but you are using it further in your program this way in the `if` block of `for` loop:

```
sum_evens = sum_evens + cc_digits[i];
```

So, this results in undefined behaviour and thus abnormal values appear. To avoid this, try initializing `sum_evens`.

```
int sum_evens = 0, sum_odds = 0;
```